# Grant Permission to a multiple people picker column

Tags: permissions, people-picker, workflow, ajax

I won't lose any time so here's what I need help with:

I have been trying for a few days to grant contribute & read permissions to the people in 3 people picker columns in a form, the permissions must be reset and regranted every time an item is created or changed, well here's the tricky part. Two of those columns are multiple people columns.

what I have tried so far:
-Workflow of course, but the grant permission action only grants a single permission to a single person or group, it doesn't work for multiple people columns.
-An ajax call, I tried to test the grant permission with a single line of text column containing the account name of one the people I wanted to give access and it worked so I figured make a query when an edit form is opened and a new form is "ok"ed and then parse the response and fill an army of single line of texts and grant permission to them. But when I alerted the returned xml of the call, it doesn't seem to have the account name.

Does anyone have any suggestion it will be much appreciated :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know C#, then I'd recommend writing an EventReceiver to apply the permissions in your overridden ItemAdded() and ItemUpdated() methods.